# Converting if statements to a switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

My goal is to simplify my function using switch statements but I can't figure out how to include a piece of code into the switch statements. If I add in the `printf("(");` and `infixTree(node->left);` wouldn't they get called at unexpected times if I added those lines of code under each case?

Here is my current function.

```
void infixTree(ExpNode* node)
{   
    if(node->type==INTEGER)
    {
        printf("%d",node->value.value.iVal);
        return;
    }

    if(node->type==DOUBLE)
    {
        printf("%f",node->value.value.dVal);
        return;
    }

    if(node->type==SYMBOL)
    {
        printf("%s",node->symbol);
        return;
    }

    printf("(");
    infixTree(node->left);

    if(node->type==ADD_OP)
    {
        printf(" + ");
    }
    else if(node->type==SUB_OP)
    {
        printf(" - ");
    }
    else if(node->type==MUL_OP)
    {
        printf(" * ");
    }
    else if(node->type==DIV_OP)
    {
        printf(" / ");
    }
    else if(node->type==MOD_OP)
    {
        printf(" %% ");
    }
    else if(node->type==ASSIGN_OP)
    {
        printf(" = ");
    }

    infixTree(node->right);
    printf(")");
}
```

I don't know how I would include

```
printf("(");
infixTree(node->left);
```

My function using switch statements looks like this at the moment.

```
void infixTree(ExpNode* node)
{
    switch(node->type) 
    {
        case INTEGER :
            printf("%d", node->value.value.iVal);
            return; 
        case DOUBLE :
            printf("%f", node->value.value.dVal);
            return;
        case SYMBOL :
            printf*%s", node->symbol);
            return;
    }

    switch(node->type)
    {
        case ADD_OP:
            printf("(");
            infixTree(node->left);
            printf(" + ");
            break;
        case SUB_OP:
            printf("(");
            infixTree(node->left);
            printf(" - ");
            break;
        case MUL_OP :
            printf("(");
            infixTree(node->left);
            printf(" * ");
            break;
        case DIV_OP :
            printf("(");
            infixTree(node->left);
            printf(" / ");
            break;
        case MOD_OP :
            printf("(");
            infixTree(node->left);
            printf(" %% ");
            break;
        case ASSIGN_OP :
            printf("(");
            infixTree(node->left);
            printf(" = ");
            break;
    }

    infixTree(node->right);
    printf(")");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake. It should have been there. Edited

Comment: You can have two different `switch`es, like you have two different elsif ladders.

Comment: Okay I edited it, Would that solution work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to include

```
printf("(");
infixTree(node->left);
```

in all switch branches.

For the sake of compaction, I would write

```
printf("(");
infixTree(node->left);
switch(node->type){
    case ADD_OP:
        printf(" + ");
        break;
    case SUB_OP:
        printf(" - ");
        break;
    case MUL_OP :
        printf(" * ");
        break;
    case DIV_OP :
        printf(" / ");
        break;
    case MOD_OP :
        printf(" %% ");
        break;
    case ASSIGN_OP :
        printf(" = ");
        break;
}
```

Comment: So just before the first case in the second switch statement?

Comment: @FatFockFrank Yes. See my edited answer

Comment: Another question. Those cases are enumeration values. When i don't Include all of the enumeration values in each switch, I receive an error. `warning: enumeration value 'INTEGER' not handled in switch`. Can I ignore this?

Comment: You can add a `default: break;` branch to eliminate this warning.